# .show() on a returned AlertDialog throws FATAL EXCEPTION

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

### My setup

I've built a `CopyPaste.java` class which allows me to use all of the methods in there to control copying and pasting to the clipboard.

My first problem was this:

The `CopyPaste` class needed to create a dialog to show to the user to select either copy, or paste. The `CopyPaste` class is *not* part of my Activity class, therefore I cannot display an alert from that class.

If anyone has a workaround for that problem, I'll work with that (it's prefered).

However, to fix that problem, I simply made the method in `CopyPaste` `return` the `AlertDialog` that was created, and then I would display it when I was in my Activity class.

---

### The code

I have to create an instance of my `CopyPaste` class because that class' methods require the `Context`.

So this is how it's set up:

```
public class CopyPaste {

    private Context c = null;
    public CopyPaste(Context c) {
        this.c = c;
    }
...
```

And to create the instance from my Activity class, it's this:

```
CopyPaste copyAndPaste;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);

    copyAndPaste = new CopyPaste(getApplicationContext());
    ...
```

In my Activity class, this is is how I use the methods that are in the `CopyPaste`:

```
final EditText e = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
e.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) 
{
    if (e.length() == 0) {
        copyAndPaste .pasteOption(e).show(); // pasteOption returns AlertDialog
    }
}
```

The `pasteOption` method is the method from `CopyPaste` that returns the created `AlertDialog`, like this:

```
public AlertDialog pasteOption(final EditText e) {
    try {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
        builder.setCancelable(true)
        .setNeutralButton("Paste", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                paste(e);
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        //alert.show();
        return alert;

    } catch(Exception q) { 
        q.printStackTrace(); 
        toast("Error!"); 
        return null; 
    }
}
```

### The error

When I long click on the EditText to bring up the alert, I don't have a caught exception (the toast doesn't say "Error!"). So, the method `pasteOption` is properly returning the `AlertDialog`, but instead the error occurs on the line (that's line 100 from `CentralTendency.java` in the LogCat):

```
copyAndPaste.pasteOption(e).show(); // pasteOption returns AlertDialog
```

On that note, here is the LogCat:

```
02-22 22:08:53.522: E/AndroidRuntime(12335): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-22 22:08:53.522: E/AndroidRuntime(12335): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
02-22 22:08:53.522: E/AndroidRuntime(12335):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:800)
02-22 22:08:53.522: E/AndroidRuntime(12335):    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:288)
02-22 22:08:53.522: E/AndroidRuntime(12335):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:73)
02-22 22:08:53.522: E/AndroidRuntime(12335):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:287)
02-22 22:08:53.522: E/AndroidRuntime(12335):    at com.mikeyaworski.calculator.CentralTendency$3.onLongClick(CentralTendency.java:100)
02-22 22:08:53.522: E/AndroidRuntime(12335):    at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:4525)
02-22 22:08:53.522: E/AndroidRuntime(12335):    at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:9575)
02-22 22:08:53.522: E/AndroidRuntime(12335):    at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:18775)
02-22 22:08:53.522: E/AndroidRuntime(12335):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
02-22 22:08:53.522: E/AndroidRuntime(12335):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-22 22:08:53.522: E/AndroidRuntime(12335):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-22 22:08:53.522: E/AndroidRuntime(12335):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
02-22 22:08:53.522: E/AndroidRuntime(12335):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-22 22:08:53.522: E/AndroidRuntime(12335):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-22 22:08:53.522: E/AndroidRuntime(12335):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
02-22 22:08:53.522: E/AndroidRuntime(12335):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
02-22 22:08:53.522: E/AndroidRuntime(12335):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprit seems to be the getApplicationContext() that you are passing in the Dialog constructor. Instead pass the activity reference.

```
copyAndPaste = new CopyPaste(getApplicationContext()); // wrong way
copyAndPaste = new CopyPaste(refToActivity); //correct way
```

Comment: And that also fixes the problem that was occuring when I was trying to display the dialog from `CopyPaste`. Now I can.